# C++ how to input certain things in vector

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, vector

I have a empty vector that I need to fill with binary numbers 1 and 0, and when user inputs something other then 0 and 1 the size of vector is complete.
I tried something like this:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespade std;

bool task1() {
vector<int> binV
int input = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < binV.size; i++) {
    cout << "Enter binary number: " << " ";
    if (input == 1 && input == 0) {
        cin >> input;
        binV.push_back(input);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Wrong input, the size of vector is complete";
    }
}
return 0;
}
int main() {
    task1();
}
```

I made simple loop for inputing and made this if/else statement which is incorrect I presume but didn't find solution to my task and I ran into code problems C2446 and C3867 which I don't understand since I'm not expert in C++

Comment: Code needs to be inside a `main()` function.

Comment: I forgot to add that when I was editing question now its okay

Comment: @BeginnerAlibi `binV.size;` you have a typo there, this must be `binV.size();`

Comment: Code is now okay but vector is empty loop will break; because there is no size in vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vector has zero length at start

```
vector<int> binV;  //zero length
```

In this line of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < binV.size(); i++){//some code}
```

Will not run because binV is empty

This expression is not correct

```
if (input == 1 && input == 0)    //not valid
```

This `&&` is logical and operator, if one of the conditions is false this expression will return false
You need to use logical or `||` operator

```
if (input == 1 || input == 0)
```

If you want to break your for loop if the value is different from 1 or 0

```
for (int i = 0; i < binV.size(); i++) {
cout << "Enter binary number: " << " ";
if (input == 1 || input == 0) {
    cin >> input;
    binV.push_back(input);
}
else {
    cout << "Wrong input, the size of vector is complete";
    break;    //here
}
```

the `break;` command will end the loop

> break statement causes the enclosing for, range-for, while or do-while loop or switch statement to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

Use || instead of && in your if statement. Also the size of your vector (binV.size()) in the comparison of your for loop is 0, so your loop will not run. You'd might want to try a do while loop instead. Hope I was of some help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in `binV.size;`
You need to replace it with `binV.size();`